# Android Development -- Input Methods

Tags: android, text, methods, input

I just got AVD up and running, and I got a "HelloWorld" to work.
Now I figure the next logical step would be to get a bit more familar with I/O, so, I want to create and input box and have a button (or some sort of trigger) to hit when the person finishes input, and then to read it in, and output responses based on the input.

I've tried to use the Android Developers Resources, and it said that to create and input method, I needed to edit the AndroidManifest.xml and to add the service into it. So, my xml now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hunter.nance.escapetheroom"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application



    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidEscapeTheRoomActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="FastInputIME"
        android:label="@string/fast_input_label"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>

</application>
```

However, my Eclipse file says error:

```
[2012-02-27 11:44:41 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\Documents and Settings\java\workspace\AndroidEscapeTheRoom\AndroidManifest.xml: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/AndroidEscapeTheRoom/AndroidManifest.xml'.
[2012-02-27 11:44:41 - AndroidEscapeTheRoom] AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package: Build aborted.
```

Not to mention, even after getting the XML to work, I'm not sure how to utilize it in my actual Java code. Are there any good tutorials for this or any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try right clicking onto your project in the eclipse project explorer and choose "refresh". This should sync with the filesystem again. Apart from that: It sounds to that you mix things up a bit, so please clarify: You want an edittext (=text input field) and a few buttons plus a TextView to show some output text? You mention an InputMethod service, which means you try to create a custom soft-keyboard. This is somewhat advanced, so just to make sure you are aware of what you are doing (and that you possibly run in the wrong direction).

Comment: Thanks, I'll clarify:
I want there to be an input box, where the user can tap it, and a keyboard appears which they can use to type into.
Then, I want there to be a button which the user presses when they are done typing, and on that event, the Java code will check to see if it matches preset possiblities, and, if it does, then...
A final text box will display text based on the input. 

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah then you are on the wrong way. The classes you look for are `EditText` (=input field), `Button` and `TextView` (=a text label). There are some small tutorials on the dev site that you can check out to get started, e.g. [Form Stuff (esp. the edittext section)](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText) or [Hello LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) for a layout that contain these 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any permissions to put a textInput and manipulate it's data. Open your layouts folder, then your Main xml file and go to design view. You can then drag and drop a text input. About the Java code, you go to your src folder, then in your package you'll find one java file. To get a reference to your text input you'll need something like this.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mytextinput); //considering your input id is mytextinput.
```

then you can get and set it's text by using two methods:

```
String myText = et.getText().toString();
et.setText("my new text for input box");
```

try watching this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sS-ylTxi40

UPDATE:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
  tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
}
});
```

This code will do exactly what you want. Just don't forget to put the controls with same id-s in xml :)

Comment: I'm watching a lot of these videos. They're extremely useful. Thanks a ton, Gio.

Comment: no problem. to make a button actually do something you'll have to add a listener to it.. I'll update my answer with it's code

Comment: The code compiles fine, and everything seems like it should work, but when I run it on my AVD, it instantly says "Unfortunately, Hello, Android has stopped" (still using that as the name.) There are no errors marked on the XML nor the Java code, and no errors are output to the console. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Actually, I think it shows errors on LogCat, but it just says the errors are at 'performLaunchActivity' :/

Comment: make sure your class's onCreate starts something like this:
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: Also, I'd make a new project and start testing out there instead of using the old one, because sometimes eclipse fails when I have everything right. When I move all my classes and xmls to new project everything works as it should.

Comment: I tried both of those to no avail. Now I realized that the original error causing it not to run is a NullPointerException, but, I don't know where. It says "Unable to instantiate ComponentInfo" due to the NullPointer. Thanks a ton for the help. I'm going to try and ask it as a separate question so that I can post my code.

Comment: Okay.. I've recorded a short video to show you how to make this project. You can also download source along with comments from the link in description. http://youtu.be/KSIAJYSzlzw

Comment: Thank you very much. It would seem the problem was that I didn't have them marked as 'final,' so I thought I had to make them outside of the onCreate method. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well you can't use the findViewById() method without activity being set. No problem :)